# Denying Access to Particular IPs on Apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess, spam-prevention, mod-access

One of my websites is being continuously attacked by spammers originating from a certain set of countries.

There are four culprit IPs that are proving to be a nuisance.

I have tried using the mod_access utility of Apache and have the following lines added to my .htaccess

```
<Limit GET POST>
order allow,deny
Allow from all
deny from 201.xx.xx.xx
deny from 202.xx.xx.x
deny from 201.xx.xx.xx
deny from 201.xx.xxx.xx
</Limit>
```

Howeverm for some reason, the spammers are still able to access my site and the spam continuous from the said IPs

Can anyone tell me as to where exactly it is that I am going wrong.

Comment: Just comment out `<Limit>` lines

Comment: Are you sure you have `order allow,deny`, and not `order deny,allow`?

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the limit

```
order allow,deny
deny from 201.xx.xx.xx
deny from 202.xx.xx.x
deny from 201.xx.xx.xx
deny from 201.xx.xxx.xx
allow from all
```